# Find event handlers for a node

Tags: javascript, dom-events, yui

I want suspend the click event for a node temporarily .

I want to get the click event handler for a node and detach it and then reattach it when I want it again.

I am using YUI 3.

Can some one tell me how could I query the click event handlers for a node and detach them?

Answer (score 1):

See Y.Event.getListeners - http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Event.html#method_getListeners

For all the various ways you can detach events, see http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/#detach-methods

Comment: `.destroy(true)` worked for me! :D but, oddly enough, I've done `Y.one('*').purge(true)` and it still seems like there are events attached. Try it on [any](//cregox.com/test) squarespace site. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

on() returns a subscription object that can be used to unbind that subscription

```
var subscription = myNode.on("click", handleClick);

//unbind the subscription
subscription.detach();
```

Or you can use the Node's detach() method if you didnt get the subscription object

```
myNode.detach("click", handleClick); //detaches only handleClick
```

or if you want to dettach all click handlers :

`node.detach('click');`