# How do I remove YUI delegated events?

Tags: javascript, yui

I'm attempting to create a script for a platform that allows users to inject javascript. They are using YUI and specifically `Y.one('body).delegate('click',...)` to attach an event to a button. I would like to intercept this button but I cannot figure out how to stop, block, remove or otherwise prevent the event handler from firing.

**Note:** I don't have direct access to the handler returned by `Y.delegate()

So far I've tried

```
Y.detachAll('click');
Y.unsubscribeAll('click');
Y.one('body').detachAll('click');
Y.one('body').unsubscribeAll('click');
Y.one('.the-delegated-class').detachAll('click');
Y.one('.the-delegated-class').unsubscribeAll('click');
```

All to no avail. In fact the only success I've had is to completely remove and replace the body HTML which obviously takes all the event handlers with it as opposed to just the one I want to remove.

Any insights?

Comment: That platform isn't squarespace by any chance, is it? :P

Comment: @Cawas Yes it is, not sure why I was so vague...:-/

Comment: Quite related then, I'm using `destroy(true)`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9405055/274502

Comment: That seems like overkill to me with potentially unwanted side affects though probably not enough to trump the fact that it works for you ...http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Node.html#method_destroy

Comment: This might be helpful: https://answers.squarespace.com/questions/100302/remove-an-event-listener-in-squarespace.html?childToView=107136#answer-107136

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out one of my attempts was the correct method but my usage was wrong. I was (unknowingly) attempting to detach the event prior to it being attached in the first place.

That said in the case of:
`Y.one('body).delegate('click',...)`

This works:
`Y.one('body').detach('click')`

Though ideally you'd call detach direct on the EventHandle returned by the delegate call.

Answer (score 0):

The delegate Event method does not appear to store the handles anywhere, you could potentially create a patch replacement for Event.delegate that stores the handles against the delegate element.  A basic example of patching YUI: https://gist.github.com/tivac/1424351

Untested code:

```
var config = {
    groups : {
        patches : {
            base : "/js/patches/",
            modules : {
                "node-event-delegate-patches" : {
                    path : "node-event-delegate.js",
                    condition : {
                        name : "node-event-delegate-patches",
                        trigger : "node-event-delegate",
                        test : function() { return true; }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

YUI.add("node-event-delegate-patches", function(Y) {
    var L = Y.Lang;

    Y.Node.prototype.delegate = function(type) {
        var args = Y.Array(arguments, 0, true),
            handle,
            index = (L.isObject(type) && !L.isArray(type)) ? 1 : 2;
        args.splice(index, 0, this._node);

        if (!L.isArray(this._node._delegate_event_handles)){
            this._node._delegate_event_handles = [];
        }
        handle = Y.delegate.apply(Y, args);
        this._node._delegate_event_handles.push( handle );
        return handle;
    };

    Y.Node.prototype.detachDelegates = function(){
        Y.Array.each(this._node._delegate_event_handles, function(handle){
            handle.detach();
        });
    }
});
```